# Metric for prioritising SQL SERVER dm_exec_procedure_stats

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

This query provides A LOT of useful information, but I need to come up with a good metric for prioritising the data. Can anyone come up with an ideal sequence for the ORDER BY clause?

I'm guessing the key fields for calculating the priority order will be [execution_count], [total_worker_time], [total_physical_reads] and [total_logical_writes]

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(database_id)               databaes_name
    ,p.name                                 proc_name
    ,p.type                                 proc_type
    ,d.object_id
    ,d.type
    ,d.type_desc
    --,d.sql_handle
    --,d.plan_handle
    ,d.cached_time
    ,d.last_execution_time
    ,d.execution_count
    ,d.total_worker_time
    ,d.last_worker_time
    ,d.min_worker_time
    ,d.max_worker_time
    ,d.total_physical_reads
    ,d.last_physical_reads
    ,d.min_physical_reads
    ,d.max_physical_reads
    ,d.total_logical_writes
    ,d.last_logical_writes
    ,d.min_logical_writes
    ,d.max_logical_writes
    ,d.total_logical_reads
    ,d.last_logical_reads
    ,d.min_logical_reads
    ,d.max_logical_reads
    ,d.total_elapsed_time
    ,d.last_elapsed_time
    ,d.min_elapsed_time
    ,d.max_elapsed_time
FROM   
    sys.procedures p
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats d
            ON 
            p.object_id = d.object_id
WHERE  
    d.database_id = Db_id()
```

Can any one suggest an additional DMV I should be looking at to figure out what my most expensive Stored Procedures are?

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: I'm currently looking at 2008R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article is a great read on the subject.  [Simple-Talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/which-of-your-stored-procedures-are-using-the-most-resources/)

But to answer your question I would suggest using this:

```
ORDER BY AVG_LOGICAL_READS DESC
```

By doing this you can see which procedure has done the most logical I/O’s per execution.

You should also look at this, even though it is specific to queries versus procedures.  It has a ton of information related to the subject.   [SQL Authority Most Expensive Queries](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/14/sql-server-find-most-expensive-queries-using-dmv/)  It includes this snippet:

> ```
> SELECT TOP 10 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
> ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
> WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
> ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
> END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
> qs.execution_count,
> qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
> qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
> qs.total_worker_time,
> qs.last_worker_time,
> qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
> qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
> qs.last_execution_time,
> qp.query_plan
> FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
> CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
> CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
> ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC -- logical reads
> -- ORDER BY qs.total_logical_writes DESC -- logical writes
> -- ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
> ```

Comment: When I'm analysing dm_db_missing_index_xxx I use ORDER BY [avg_total_user_cost] * [avg_user_impact] * ([user_seeks] + [user_scans]) DESC. Do you have any suggestions along that line?

Comment: look at using AVG_ESTIMATED_IMPACT.  Look at this for more details on missing indexes  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/01/03/sql-server-2008-missing-index-script-download/   Hopefully this will be of service to you.